# Why is Ansible immediately terminating the newly created EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I'm using the following Ansible task to create an EC2 VM. This task previously worked but now when I run it, the task creates EC2 VM which then terminates causing subsequent tasks to fail.

Here is the task:

```
  # Create VM3
  - name: Create EC2 instance
    ec2_instance:
      name: "VM3"
      key_name: "My Key"
      instance_type: t2.medium
      image_id: ami-09e67e426f25ce0d7
      wait: yes
      security_groups:
      - "Custom Security Group"
      - default
      vpc_subnet_id: "{{ subnet_id }}"
      network:
        assign_public_ip: yes
      region: us-east-1
      state: running
    register: vm3
```

At the end of the task, I get the following warning. I've googled but haven't found this error message anywhere.

```
[WARNING]: Instances i-000d77bcef857ab6e took too long to reach state OK.
Waiter InstanceStatusOk failed: Max attempts exceeded
```

I found this Troubleshooting page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/troubleshooting-launch.html#troubleshooting-launch-internal

This says to check the state transition reason. The reason I see is:

```
"StateReason": {
    "Code": "Client.UserInitiatedShutdown",
    "Message": "Client.UserInitiatedShutdown: User initiated shutdown"
}
```

The troubleshooting guide naturally doesn't have any guidance for this. Interestingly, this same code does create the instance on another account that I have.

EDIT: Adding system log

I don't really know what to make of this. I removed the beginning because it was too long.

```
...
Welcome to [1mUbuntu 20.04.2 LTS[0m!

[    2.144147] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <ubuntu>.
[    2.150246] systemd[1]: Initializing machine ID from random generator.
[    2.154577] systemd[1]: Installed transient /etc/machine-id file.
[    2.423417] tsc: Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 2400.001 MHz
[    2.427721] clocksource: tsc: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x22983858435, max_idle_ns: 440795258295 ns
[    2.441562] systemd[1]: Created slice system-modprobe.slice.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Created slice [0;1;39msystem-modprobe.slice[0m.
[    2.449662] systemd[1]: Created slice system-serial\x2dgetty.slice.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Created slice [0;1;39msystem-serial\x2dgetty.slice[0m.
[    2.458349] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Created slice [0;1;39mUser and Session Slice[0m.
[    2.465924] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mForward Password R…uests to Wall Directory Watch[0m.
[    2.475208] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Set up automount [0;1;39mArbitrary…s File System Automount Point[0m.
[    2.485909] systemd[1]: Reached target User and Group Name Lookups.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mUser and Group Name Lookups[0m.
[    2.493352] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mSlices[0m.
[    2.499213] systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mSwap[0m.
[    2.505082] systemd[1]: Listening on Device-mapper event daemon FIFOs.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mDevice-mapper event daemon FIFOs[0m.
[    2.513193] systemd[1]: Listening on LVM2 poll daemon socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mLVM2 poll daemon socket[0m.
[    2.520614] systemd[1]: Listening on multipathd control socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mmultipathd control socket[0m.
[    2.528685] systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mSyslog Socket[0m.
[    2.535791] systemd[1]: Listening on fsck to fsckd communication Socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mfsck to fsckd communication Socket[0m.
[    2.544125] systemd[1]: Listening on initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39minitctl Compatibility Named Pipe[0m.
[    2.552104] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Audit Socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mJournal Audit Socket[0m.
[    2.559018] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mJournal Socket (/dev/log)[0m.
[    2.566285] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mJournal Socket[0m.
[    2.572911] systemd[1]: Listening on Network Service Netlink Socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mNetwork Service Netlink Socket[0m.
[    2.581658] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mudev Control Socket[0m.
[    2.589141] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mudev Kernel Socket[0m.
[    2.596872] systemd[1]: Mounting Huge Pages File System...
         Mounting [0;1;39mHuge Pages File System[0m...
[    2.604063] systemd[1]: Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
         Mounting [0;1;39mPOSIX Message Queue File System[0m...
[    2.612044] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Debug File System...
         Mounting [0;1;39mKernel Debug File System[0m...
[    2.620147] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Trace File System...
         Mounting [0;1;39mKernel Trace File System[0m...
[    2.628185] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
         Starting [0;1;39mJournal Service[0m...
[    2.634862] systemd[1]: Starting Set the console keyboard layout...
         Starting [0;1;39mSet the console keyboard layout[0m...
[    2.643808] systemd[1]: Starting Create list of static device nodes for the current kernel...
         Starting [0;1;39mCreate list of st…odes for the current kernel[0m...
[    2.657622] systemd[1]: Starting Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling...
         Starting [0;1;39mMonitoring of LVM…meventd or progress polling[0m...
[    2.669816] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Module drm...
         Starting [0;1;39mLoad Kernel Module drm[0m...
[    2.682654] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Set Up Additional Binary Formats being skipped.
[    2.696388] systemd[1]: Starting File System Check on Root Device...
         Starting [0;1;39mFile System Check on Root Device[0m...
[    2.709076] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
         Starting [0;1;39mLoad Kernel Modules[0m...
[    2.717657] systemd[1]: Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
         Starting [0;1;39mudev Coldplug all Devices[0m...
[    2.732587] systemd[1]: Starting Uncomplicated firewall...
         Starting [0;1;39mUncomplicated firewall[0m...
[    2.748540] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mJournal Service[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted [0;1;39mHuge Pages File System[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted [0;1;39mPOSIX Message Queue File System[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted [0;1;39mKernel Debug File System[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted [0;1;39mKernel Trace File System[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mSet the console keyboard layout[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mCreate list of st… nodes for the current kernel[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mLoad Kernel Module drm[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mFile System Check on Root Device[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mLoad Kernel Modules[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mUncomplicated firewall[0m.
         Mounting [0;1;39mFUSE Control File System[0m...
         Mounting [0;1;39mKernel Configuration File System[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mFile System Check Daemon to report status[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mRemount Root and Kernel File Systems[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mApply Kernel Variables[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted [0;1;39mFUSE Control File System[0m.[    2.831907] EXT4-fs (xvda1): re-mounted. Opts: discard

[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted [0;1;39mKernel Configuration File System[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mRemount Root and Kernel File Systems[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mudev Coldplug all Devices[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mApply Kernel Variables[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mFlush Journal to Persistent Storage[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mLoad/Save Random Seed[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mCreate System Users[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mudev Wait for Complete Device Initialization[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mLoad/Save Random Seed[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mFlush Journal to Persistent Storage[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mCreate System Users[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mCreate Static Device Nodes in /dev[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mCreate Static Device Nodes in /dev[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mudev Kernel Device Manager[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mudev Kernel Device Manager[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mDispatch Password …ts to Console Directory Watch[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mLocal Encrypted Volumes[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Found device [0;1;39m/dev/ttyS0[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mLoad/Save RF …itch Status /dev/rfkill Watch[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mudev Wait for Complete Device Initialization[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mDevice-Mapper Multipath Device Controller[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mMonitoring of LVM… dmeventd or progress polling[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mDevice-Mapper Multipath Device Controller[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mLocal File Systems (Pre)[0m.
         Mounting [0;1;39mMount unit for am…on-ssm-agent, revision 3552[0m...
         Mounting [0;1;39mMount unit for core18, revision 1997[0m...
         Mounting [0;1;39mMount unit for lxd, revision 19647[0m...
         Mounting [0;1;39mMount unit for snapd, revision 11588[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted [0;1;39mMount unit for amazon-ssm-agent, revision 3552[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted [0;1;39mMount unit for lxd, revision 19647[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted [0;1;39mMount unit for core18, revision 1997[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted [0;1;39mMount unit for snapd, revision 11588[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mLocal File Systems[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mLoad AppArmor profiles[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mSet console font and keymap[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mCreate final runt…dir for shutdown pivot root[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mTell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mCommit a transient machine-id on disk[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mCreate Volatile Files and Directories[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mSet console font and keymap[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mCreate final runt…e dir for shutdown pivot root[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mTell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mCommit a transient machine-id on disk[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mCreate Volatile Files and Directories[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mNetwork Time Synchronization[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mUpdate UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mUpdate UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mNetwork Time Synchronization[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mSystem Time Set[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mSystem Time Synchronized[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mLoad AppArmor profiles[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Removed slice [0;1;39msystem-modprobe.slice[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped target [0;1;39mSystem Time Synchronized[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped target [0;1;39mSystem Time Set[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Closed [0;1;39mLVM2 poll daemon socket[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Closed [0;1;39mLoad/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch[0m.
         Stopping [0;1;39mCreate final runt…dir for shutdown pivot root[0m...
         Stopping [0;1;39mLoad/Save Random Seed[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Removed slice [0;1;39msystem-serial\x2dgetty.slice[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mSet console scheme[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped target [0;1;39mUser and Group Name Lookups[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped target [0;1;39mSlices[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Removed slice [0;1;39mUser and Session Slice[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Closed [0;1;39mSyslog Socket[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped target [0;1;39mLocal Encrypted Volumes[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped [0;1;39mDispatch Password …ts to Console Directory Watch[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped [0;1;39mForward Password R…uests to Wall Directory Watch[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped target [0;1;39mSwap[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mLoad AppArmor pro…managed internally by snapd[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped [0;1;39mCommit a transient machine-id on disk[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped [0;1;39mApply Kernel Variables[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped [0;1;39mLoad Kernel Modules[0m.
         Stopping [0;1;39mNetwork Time Synchronization[0m...
         Stopping [0;1;39mUpdate UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped [0;1;39mNetwork Time Synchronization[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped [0;1;39mLoad/Save Random Seed[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mSet console scheme[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped [0;1;39mUpdate UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped [0;1;39mCreate Volatile Files and Directories[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped [0;1;39mCreate final runtime dir for shutdown pivot root[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped target [0;1;39mLocal File Systems[0m.
         Unmounting [0;1;39mMount unit for …on-ssm-agent, revision 3552[0m...
         Unmounting [0;1;39mMount unit for core18, revision 1997[0m...
         Unmounting [0;1;39mMount unit for lxd, revision 19647[0m...
         Unmounting [0;1;39mMount unit for snapd, revision 11588[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Unmounted [0;1;39mMount unit for amazon-ssm-agent, revision 3552[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Unmounted [0;1;39mMount unit for core18, revision 1997[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Unmounted [0;1;39mMount unit for lxd, revision 19647[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Unmounted [0;1;39mMount unit for snapd, revision 11588[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped target [0;1;39mLocal File Systems (Pre)[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mUnmount All Filesystems[0m.
         Stopping [0;1;39mMonitoring of LVM…meventd or progress polling[0m...
         Stopping [0;1;39mDevice-Mapper Multipath Device Controller[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped [0;1;39mCreate Static Device Nodes in /dev[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped [0;1;39mCreate System Users[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped [0;1;39mRemount Root and Kernel File Systems[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped [0;1;39mFile System Check on Root Device[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped [0;1;39mDevice-Mapper Multipath Device Controller[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped [0;1;39mMonitoring of LVM2… dmeventd or progress polling[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mShutdown[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mFinal Step[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mPower-Off[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mPower-Off[0m.
[    6.323873] reboot: Power down
```

Comment: Did you look at system logs? EC2 ->  Actions > Instance Settings > Get System Log.

Comment: @omuthu Thanks for pointing me to the logs. I don't really know what I'm looking for. I see that it tried to reboot but I don't see why. The State transition reason says 'user initiated.'